# Taking a screenshot of all sides of a Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Currently, I have a Canvas that I have the following script that prints canvas to png image.
Right now it prints just based on which view you have the canvas rotated on.  I have seen someone else have a script that takes a screenshot of the canvas (front, back, left and right) and add all the images to a PDF file.  How is this possible?

This is my script now:

```
document.getElementById('save').onclick=()=>{
  saveImage()
}
function saveImage() {
  const canvas =  document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]
  const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = image.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
  a.download="carport.png"
  a.click();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what a canvas (front, back, left and right) is?

Comment: So you have a 3D image that is drawn to canvas ... and your code shows you know how to take a screenshot ... what exactly are you having troubles with?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda - Yes I have a 3D image and the button does take a screenshot right now and save it as a PNG file.  I saw someone else save their 3D image as a PDF with 1 click they saved the 3D image in four different areas.  The front of the image, in my case a carport.  The Right side, left side and the back of the carport as well.

Comment: There is no magic bullet to take multiple images of a canvas, you have to draw the 3D image on each angle then take each screenshot ... we can do all that using an invisible canvas, that way the user does not see the different angles but we still drawing to a canvas multiple times ... you should post a minimal but complete code sample

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish I get a feeling that a video might be better than just a few images

Comment: @KJ  you taged me, but I think you meant to tag the original writer of the question which you don't need to tag since you are commenting on his question ... but looking at this big picture best this is close since question just raises more questions